# sum of series $\sum_{k = 0}^n (-1/4)^k \cos((\pi/4) k)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the sum of series $$\sum_{k=0}^n \left(-\frac14\right)^k \cdot \cos \left(\frac{k\pi}4\right) \text{ ?}$$

I was trying to see over some inputs its behavior: (to see if cos has some interesting information) for $n=1: (1/2)^{0.5}$, $n=2:0$,   $n=3$: $-(1/2)^{0.5}$ $n=4: -1$, $n=5:-(1/2)^{0.5}$, $n=6$: $(3/4)^{0.5},\ldots$ but with no conclusions. It reminds a bit of fourier series, but it isn't a function of $x$.

Comment: The $\cos(k\pi/4)$ term is periodic in $k$ so get it's closed form to start things out, then insert that into the general term, etc.

Comment: Split into a number of sums where each sum the cos factor evaluates to the same number. Then evaluate each of them.

Comment: @coffeemath I can't get the closed form, because from the inputs the outputs doesn't seems to have any pattern. Is it Euler's formula?

Comment: The cos is a periodic function. Check out what values it takes. Then you will be left with geometric series as Barry explained.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the series
\begin{align}
S_{n}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} e^{\frac{i k \pi}{4}} x^{k}
\end{align}
It can quickly be determined that
\begin{align}
S_{n}(x) = \frac{1 - e^{- \pi i/4} x - e^{(n+1) \pi i/4} x^{n+1} + e^{n \pi i/4} x^{n+2} }{ 1 - \sqrt{2} x + x^{2}}. 
\end{align}
Taking the real part leads to, where $Re(S_{n}(x))$ is the desired series,
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \cos\left(\frac{k \pi}{4} \right) \, x^{k} = \frac{1 - \cos(\pi/4) x - \cos((n+1) \pi/4) x^{n+1} + \cos(n \pi/4) x^{n+2} }{ 1 - \sqrt{2} x + x^{2}}.
\end{align}
Taking the imaginary part leads to
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \sin\left(\frac{k \pi}{4} \right) \, x^{k} = - \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \, \frac{1 + \sqrt{2} \left(\sin\left(\frac{(n+1)\pi}{4} \right) 
- \sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{4} \right) x \, \right) x^{n+1} }{ 1 - \sqrt{2} x + x^{2}}.
\end{align}
If $x \to \frac{1}{x}$ then the series becomes
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \cos\left(\frac{k \pi}{4} \right) \, \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{k} = \frac{x^{n+1} \left(x - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right) - x \cos\left(\frac{(n+1) \pi}{4}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{n \pi}{4}\right)}{ 
(1 - \sqrt{2} x + x^{2}) \, x^{n} }.
\end{align}

When $x = -1/4$ the result becomes
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \cos\left( \frac{k \pi}{4} \right) \, \left( \frac{-1}{4} \right)^{k} = \frac{1}{17 + 2 \sqrt{2}} \, \left[ 16 + 2 \sqrt{2} + \frac{(-1)^{n}}{4^{n}} \left( 4 \cos\left( \frac{(n+1) \pi}{4} \right) + \cos\left( \frac{n \pi}{4} \right) \right) \right]
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \sin\left( \frac{k \pi}{4} \right) \, \left( \frac{-1}{4} \right)^{k} = \frac{1}{8 + 17 \sqrt{2}} \, \left[ 2 \sqrt{2} + \frac{(-1)^{n}}{4^{n}} \left( 4 \sin\left( \frac{(n+1) \pi}{4} \right) + \sin\left( \frac{n \pi}{4} \right) \right) \right].
\end{align}
For the case $x = -4$ the series become
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \cos\left( \frac{k \pi}{4} \right) \, (-4)^{k} = \frac{1}{17 + 4 \sqrt{2}} \, \left[ 1 + 2 \sqrt{2} + (-4)^{n} \left( \cos\left( \frac{(n+1) \pi}{4} \right) + 4 \cos\left( \frac{n \pi}{4} \right) \right) \right]
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! Is it have to do something with Z-transform?

Comment: if  everything stays  the same except  (-1/4)^(k) it is (-1/4)^(-k), Would it require more than change to -4?

Comment: @tomi The method used is similar to the Z-transform. The examples have been adjusted to provide results for $x = -\frac{1}{4}$ and $x = -4$.

Comment: I meant not x=-4 but the same series except with negative polynomial x^(-k) and not x^(k)...sum(k from0 to n)(cos(pik/4)*x^(-k))

Comment: But Z-transform is for case of infinity...... can I adjust it to help me here? Thank you very much again!

Comment: @tomi A line has been added for the cosine series with powers of $\frac{1}{x}$.

Answer (score 1):

There's a sequence of 4 terms here that repeats. The first 4 terms are:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{3} = 1 -\frac{\sqrt{2}}8 + 0 + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{128} = \frac{128 - 15\sqrt{2}}{128}$$

The next 4 terms are just that sum divided by $-4^4 = -256$ and so on. So it's just a simple geometric series:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} = \frac{a}{1-r} = \frac{128 - 15\sqrt{2}}{128}\cdot\frac{256}{257} = \frac{256 - 30\sqrt{2}}{257} \approx 0.83103$$

Comment: Great work Barry. This should do, no?

Comment: So $ sum( k from 0 to n) (-1/4)^k(cos((pi/4)*k) is a geometric series? But my series is finite....

Comment: It seems it would be easy to get a finite part of it by considering $n$ mod $4$ and using the above.

Comment: The final result should have 'n' in it, a close form...how I can get it?